# How to insert array data in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I have a **product table** and **device table**.
I have joined these two tables where I have selected `device.id` & `product.name`, now I want to insert this data into my existing `device` table using `device.id`.
I want to insert multiple dropdown values in my database. Can anyone tell me how can I solve this problem? Below is my `Controller` Code-

```html
foreach ($request->all() as $value)
        {
$deviceById= Device::find($request->id);
            if($request->destination_type == 'dealer')
            {
                $deviceById->destination_location=$value->dealer_id;
            }else
            {
                $deviceById->destination_location=$value->office_id;
            }
            $deviceById->save();
        }
        flash('Device Dispatch added successfully!')->success()->important();
        return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: what is your view code .update in your question

Comment: You can make array of all dropdowns value and convert into a json string and store it in database

Answer (score 0):

You can make array of all dropdowns value and convert into a json string and store it in database

You can do something like this. Change according to your requirement. It just a logic demo.

```html
$deviceById= Device::find($request->id);
$destination = array();

foreach ($request->all() as $value)
{
    if($request->destination_type == 'dealer')
    {
        $destination[] = $value->dealer_id;
    }else
    {
        $destination[] = $value->office_id;
    }

}
$jsonString = json_encode($destination);

$deviceById->destination_location = $jsonString
$deviceById->save();

flash('Device Dispatch added successfully!')->success()->important();
return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer by I have done it another way

Answer (score 0):

I solve it this way.I had used Elequent ORM

```html
            if($request->destination_type == 'Dealer')
            {
                DB::table('devices')
                    ->whereIn('id',$request->device_list)
                    ->update(['dealer_id'=>$request->destination_location,'device_status'=>"Dispatch"]);
                flash('Device Dispatch dealer added successfully!')->success()->important();
            }else
            {
                DB::table('devices')
                    ->whereIn('id',$request->device_list)
                    ->update(['office_id'=>$request->destination_location,'device_status'=>"Dispatch"]);
                flash('Device Dispatch office added successfully!')->success()->important();
            }
```